# Android ffmpeg Output Error

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am using

https://github.com/writingminds/ffmpeg-android-java

to run ffmpeg commands on android. I am trying to overlay an image on a video. For some reason, I get the following error when I execute this command.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 strict -2 -i overlay.jpg -filter_complex [0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,4)' output.mp4

Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Could anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: any luck with that? I'm also facing this issue.

Comment: Nope. I think the issue is the build we are using. Try and build your own new version of FFMpeg. Build it with the right features. I think that the build we are using doesn't have the right things in it. I ended up abandoning FFMpeg, it increased my app size way too much and was slow.

Comment: I see. I believe I found the solution for this issue, posted as an answer =)

Comment: Awesome. Guess I was wrong. I actually know literally nothing about FFMpeg. My assumption was quite off haha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was facing this same issue and my problem was: I was calling the execute method the wrong way. The string array I was passing was something like this:

```
final String[] cmd = new String[] { "-i input.mp4 strict -2 -i overlay.jpg -filter_complex [0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,4)' output.mp4" };
```

The correct way to create this array, though, is to split the command in separate strings:

```
final String[] cmd = new String[]{ "-i", "input.mp4", "strict", "-2", "-i", "overlay.jpg", 
                "-filter_complex", "[0:v][1:v]", "overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,4)'", "output.mp4"};
```

And then call execute:

```
try {
    final FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
    ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String message) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(String message) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String message) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    });
} catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {

}
```

I found this solution on a lauffenp's comment on this issue: https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/issues/88

Comment: Hey How can you successfully run this command,Can you help me with it what am i doing wrong? I am getting this error " A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 14661 (AsyncTask #4)" for every filter_complex command